# Standardize a sample dataset

Tags: standardization, weka

I created a model with J48. Before creating the model, data were standardized. Now I want to test this model with a sample dataset. Before applying data to the model, I believe data should be standardized. But since standardization process is local to the given dataset, how should I standardize my sample dataset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could find the answer this question.

I used this https://sebastianraschka.com/faq/docs/scale-training-test.html to solve my problem